# how to "page" through the data in a Lua table used as a dictionary?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

How would I code a function to iterate through one "pages" worth of data?  Sample code would be ideal...

So say we image the size of a page is 5 items.  If we had a lua table with 18 items it would need to print out:

- Page 1: 1 to 5
- Page 2: 6 to 10
- Page 3: 11 to 15
- Page 4: 16 to 18

So assume the data is something like:

```
local data = {}
data["dog"] = {1,2,3}
data["cat"] = {1,2,3}
data["mouse"] = {1,2,3}
data["pig"] = {1,2,3}
.
.
.
```

How would one code the function that would do the equivalent of this:

```
function printPage (myTable, pageSize, pageNum)
  -- find items in "myTable" 
end
```

So in fact I'm not even sure if a Lua table used as a dictionary can even do this?  There is no specific ordering is there in such a table, so how would you be sure the order would be the same when you come back to print page 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`next`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-next) function allows you to go through a table in an order (albeit an unpredictable one). For example:

```
data = { dog = "Ralf", cat = "Tiddles", fish = "Joey", tortoise = "Fred" }

function printPage(t, size, start)
    local i = 0
    local nextKey, nextVal = start
    while i < size and nextKey ~= nil do
        nextKey, nextVal = next(t, nextKey)
        print(nextKey .. " = " .. nextVal)
        i = i + 1
    end
    return nextKey
end

local nextPage = printPage(data, 2)  -- Print the first page
printPage(data, 2, nextPage)         -- Print the second page
```

I know this isn't quite in the form you were after, but I'm sure it can be adapted quite easily.

The [`next`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-next) function returns the key after the one provided in the table, along with its value. When the end of the table is reached, it returns `nil`. If you provide `nil` as the second parameter, it returns the first key and value in the table. It's also documented [in Corona](http://developer.anscamobile.com/reference/index/next), although it appears to be identical.

Comment: thanks - I'm using Corona actually so haven't come across "next" (didn't see it in the Corona API but perhaps they only have some of the lua functions there? i.e. at http://developer.anscamobile.com/reference) - will try this out

Comment: It seems that Corona does include it, as it's documented [here](http://developer.anscamobile.com/reference/index/next).

Comment: Nice answer. I'd just add to emphasize that it is *an* order - but that order is **not** predictable (i.e. it's not the order of insertion or anything). This is quite an FAQ when dealing with tables as dictionaries.